# Youtube videos' Topic Ids dataset / dump

Tags: youtube-api, dataset, freebase

While processing youtube videos, I'm working with the youtube's API v3. The cycle goes like this:
1) Get video
2) Request API for video's topic Id
3) Find the tuple(s) on my local Freebase dump
4) Do things.

For efficiency reasons I'd like to avoid the online request on step (2), and instead do it offline. Is there any datasets/dumps I can get, that store information like:
Youtube video's ID -> video's topic ID  ?

Thanks in advance,
Orestes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube doesn't provide data dumps of video topicDetails (or any other data server by the YouTube Data API as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

There is not a store I know. But there are few things to make it more efficient. Instead of calling videos->list per each video, make all video Ids into a comma separated string and do one call. Also specify filters like items/contentdetails/topicId, so response would only return topicIds, instead of all other information.

That way you can get all your information at once, with less bandwidth.

Comment: Pretty nice idea, it didn't even crossed my mind that I could do a request with many videoIds. Thank you for showing me the right path. At the moment I got kinda annoyed that there is no dataset available with video ids, and though I'm creating one at the moment. I also gonna publish it once I'm done with.